# EF Core OrderBy with DB-side conversion

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to use `OrderBy` with specifying how data should be ordered BEFORE it's materialized? For example I have `VARCHAR` column, but I know that for certain rows with certain keys values in there are actually numbers (integers, decimals) and they won't be sorted well by default comparer.

I don't want to fetch data before it's sorted properly because `.Skip` and `.Take` would be in use, and by properly this time we would mean sorting them with conversion to integers on the DB. This can easily be done by writing raw SQL, but that would pretty much make the code impossible to be tested anymore.

Comment: You should never be ordering by numbers-stored-as-text, fix your database to store them as numbers properly and all of this goes away.

Comment: How you expect the order , give any examples !?